# ArangoDB: Illegal Document Key error while creating Graph

Tags: arangodb

I am using ArangoDb first time and having an error of *illegal document key* while creating the graph. I find no way to figure out the reason for it. The error is weird because all keys are being generated by the system itself. Below are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The name of the graph is used verbatim as document key in the `_graphs` system collection. Therefore, the restrictions for `_key` values apply for the name:

https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/data-modeling-naming-conventions-document-keys.html

The Web UI does not indicate this, unfortunately.